# How do I assign a static internal IP to GCP Windows Server Instance using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have to create a static internal IP address for windows servers using Terraform and I am on version 12.

I have this code block that I use to create the servers:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "instance1" {
  name         = var.instance_name1
  machine_type = var.machine_type
  zone         = var.zone1
  tags         = [var.instance_name1, var.env_name]
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
    size =  var.boot_disk_size
    image = data.google_compute_image.sqlserverimage.self_link
    }

    }

  network_interface {
  subnetwork = var.subnetwork
  subnetwork_project = var.subnetwork_project
 }
}
```

How can I alter this so that I can assign a static internal IP to a new windows GCP server in Terraform?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [network_ip](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance#network_ip)?

```
network_interface {
  subnetwork = var.subnetwork
  subnetwork_project = var.subnetwork_project
  network_ip = "1.2.3.4"
}
```

The chosen ip must be in the subnet range

Comment: Hi! No I haven't. Thank you, I will give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: @bluethundr I am not sure, but I do not expect this answer to work unless the private IP address has already been reserved. Please follow up with details once you have a solution or a problem.

Answer (score 0):

try once with nat_ip >>
check the link below

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance#nat_ip

Answer (score 0):

Specify `address` value. For example,

From [address-with-subnetwork](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_address#example-usage---address-with-subnetwork) documentation:

```json
resource "google_compute_address" "internal_with_subnet_and_address" {
  name         = "my-internal-address"
  subnetwork   = google_compute_subnetwork.default.id
  address_type = "INTERNAL"
  address      = "10.0.42.42"
  region       = "us-central1"
}
```

Reference: [`5254774`](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/commit/5254774342f8644f1ffa97d3cf0207dfd2732731)